# python list max() method returns only 3 digit numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

I'm an absolute beginner and working with python 3.7 and visual studio code.
I've to sum up min. and max. values from a table. Because I get a wrong result, I striped down everyting and found out that the max() function returns only the highest 3 digit number from a propper list with also 4 digit numbers... what is wrong?

```
strng=("3928\t107\t3406\t123\t2111\t2749\t223\t125\t134\t146\t3875\t1357\t508\t1534\t4002\t4417")

strng1=strng.replace('\t',' ')
mylist=strng1.split(' ')
mx=max(mylist)

print(mylist)
print(mx)

print(mylist)
print(mx)
```

return:

```
['3928', '107', '3406', '123', '2111', '2749', '223', '125', '134', '146', '3875', '1357', '508', '1534', '4002', '4417']
508
```

I've searched and read a lot around the max() function but didn't found anything helpful...
ps: min() works well

Comment: Those are strings, not numbers. Strings are sorted _alphabetically_.  `'b'` is greater than `'aaaaaaa'` in the same way that `'2'` is greater than `'1111111'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you have strings in your list not integers so the max function is not working as expected. Here is what you could do :

```
mylist = [int(x) for x in mylist]
max(mylist)
```

---

Output :

```
4417
```

Comment: To clarify: the max function *is* working properly, but it's not working *as expected* because of the input type.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you want to select the `string` that has int representation max, you could use the `key` parameter of max:

```
string = "3928\t107\t3406\t123\t2111\t2749\t223\t125\t134\t146\t3875\t1357\t508\t1534\t4002\t4417"
mx = max(string.split(), key=int)
print(mx)
```

Notice than `mx` will be an string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform them into `int`, because `strings` have different ordering:

```
strng="3928\t107\t3406\t123\t2111\t2749\t223\t125\t134\t146\t3875\t1357\t508\t1534\t4002\t4417"

mylist=strng.split('\t')
mx=max(int(x) for x in mylist)

print(mylist)
print(mx)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the list is not converted to an integer list, the max function returns the lexicographically largest string.
Try adding the line

```
int_list = [int(i) for i in mylist]
```

and then print

```
max(int_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert list of strings into int

```
strng=("1928\t107\t3406\t123\t2111\t2749\t223\t125\t134\t146\t3875\t1357\t508\t1534\t4002\t4417")
mylist=strng.split('\t')
for i in range(0, len(mylist)): 
    mylist[i] = int(mylist[i])
print(max(mylist))
```

Hope the above code solves your issue